# Content Security Policy in Embedded Service's Post-chat VF page

Tags: visualforce, liveagent, chat, xss, csp

Hi Salesforce community!

1. I have set up an embedded service with a Post-chat page, which is overriden by a simple Visualforce page.
   [image]
2. The VF page code is very simple:

> ```
> <apex:page showHeader="false">
>     Hello world!
> </apex:page>
> ```

3. CSP configuration:
   [image]
4. The chat is hosted in a community and works perfectly
5. However, when a user clicks on the Post-page button, the VF doesn't load, and **the following error is shown in the console**:

> Refused to display 'https://test-chat-gbc-developer-edition.ap16.force.com/liveAgentSetupFlow/apex/testFinalPage' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

The same happens when the chat is hosted by a public Visualforce page as well.
Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Yup, we've had the same issue.
The solution is to go to the `Site` page in Salesforce (Setup > Develop > Sites) and then add a `Trusted Domains for Inline Frames`.

Make sure you verify your `Clickjack Protection Level` too. A value of `Allow framing of site pages on external domains (Good protection)` or lower will work.